# Negative String Length

Tags: java, string

Can you have a negative string length? If so, is it the same as null?

Comment: No. What makes you think it could?

Comment: We don't want to break up the space-time continuum now do we?

Comment: Try thinking in terms of real-life strings. Do you think those things can have negative length? :)

Comment: you are asking this question to implement a string variable without any empty string or null ,so that it doest not occupy space initially .Later you may initialse.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No; the length of a string is 0 (empty string, represented as `""`) or higher. And an empty string is *not* the same as null either (in Java it is not called a *[null string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_string)*).

To better understand what null means in Java, you could check out these questions:

- [Is null an Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894149/is-null-an-object)
- [Is null a Java keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519631/is-null-a-java-keyword)

Answer (score 4):

No, never.

length is unsigned number, it can't be negative.

the first question's answer negates the second question's legitimacy.

Comment: This does not answer my question. Downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

No. String length is any positive integer, or zero. Null is not equal to zero, nor is null equal to any negative value.

Answer (score 1):

`String.length()` returns the legth of the string as a primitive `int`, so the return value can't be null.

The javadoc doesn't state that the return value can be less than zero, but that the method returns the number of characters in the string.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot construct a valid String with a negative length.

However to answer you question in more depth, the length() method is

```
public int length() {
    return count;
}
```

and you can use reflection to change the `count` to -1 or any negative `int` value.  This is highly unlikely to be useful but could create some very confusing bugs in your system.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think so except if you deliberately chose to use an offset (like -1) 
Otherwise No, any empty string is of length 0